# iOS App Archiving Failed

Tags: ios, xcode

We are facing tough time archiving our iOS app. It compiles Perfect but whenever we archive it to upload it on the app store. We face this issue. Can someone please look into it.

Note: The file 'ListingDetailView.o' is a large file with 3k+ lines of code. Can it be an issue?

Thanks a lot.

Error generated when we archive.

> ld: in section __DATA,__const reloc 0: unknown ARM scattered
>   relocation type 1 file
>
> '/Users/.../armv7/ListingDetailView.o'
>
> for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: lines of code are not the problem because we have a file with 5,5k+ lines of code building and archiving just fine.

Comment: It obviously came from your Build Settings. What are your valid architectures? I guess you tried cleaning the project and delete Derived Data? The weird part is that you can complete a Build but not an Archive.

Comment: We figured we have huge functions with hundreds of line of code. We broke it in separate functions and it works fine.